# formula leaving whitespace

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula designed to flag rows in a ListObject:

```
=IF( [@[Is Closed]]="Y", "", "Y")
```

I have some vba code that looks for these value via StrCmp, and was surprised to find that the Text property of the cell was " Y " (as opposed to "Y").

There are some obvious easy work arounds but can someone explain why the formula  is leaving whitespace and how to force it not to?

Cheers,

UPDATE

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' FindAllInColumn
' To find a value regardless of hidden rows and autofulter settings that can make
' other methods unreliable
'
' aSearchRange  :  the range of data to search, which MUST be a single column
' aLookUpVal    :  the value
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function FindAllInColumn(aSearchRange As Range, aLookUpVal As Variant) As Excel.Range
    Debug.Assert aSearchRange.Columns.Count = 1

    Dim rngEach As Range
    Dim rngResult As Excel.Range

    For Each rngEach In aSearchRange
'        Debug.Print rngEach.Address & ": Value " & rngEach.Text
'        If IsValued(rngEach.Text) Then Stop

        If (StrComp(rngEach.Text, aLookUpVal) = 0) Then
            If rngResult Is Nothing Then
                Set rngResult = rngEach
            Else
                Set rngResult = Application.Union(rngResult, rngEach)
            End If
        End If
    Next rngEach

    Set FindAllInColumn = rngResult
End Function
```

The FIX

```
StrComp(rngEach.Value2, aLookUpVal, vbTextCompare)
```

Changing .Text to .Value2 instead. Odd, but at least it works now

Comment: This looks really strange. Can you select value with the formula and rin the following - `?StrComp("Y",selection,vbTextCompare)` in the immediate window?

Comment: Great thought - and works as expected! I posted the offending code along with motivation for it - do you see anything there?

Comment: I do not see anything strange. Just the fact, that you are declaring `Excel.Range` and `Range` separately makes me think a bit - are you wokring only in Excel or are you working in Word/PowerPoint as well?

Comment: @Vityata. Yeah, good spot, just Excel. Qualifying the range makes it look more consistent but doesn't fix the odd accumulation of whitespace

Comment: honestly strange. When you run this `?Len(Selection)` on the immediate window what do you get?

Comment: @Vityata:  Found it, but still makes no sense! See edit

Comment: @Berryl - Instead of using a `Y` or ` ` as your binary answer, why not use real boolean logic. Change the formula to `=[@[Is Closed]]="Y"`, which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, something more intuitive for Excel to work with on *many* levels.

Comment: @Berryl - `.Value2` is a cure for plenty of problems in Excel.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman. Yeah that would be an obvious work around. The column is visible though, and the "Y" is justg easier on the eyes, which is why I prefer using it

Comment: @Berryl - I used to do the same thing ... until i needed to start writing logic of those values consistently and found its much easier to write `=IF(cell,value,other)` versus `=IF(cell="answer",value,other)`. Seems small, but in big formulas its siginficant.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman. You are preaching to the choir, from the formula perspective! Then I put on my User hat and find all the TRUE, FALSE values just butt ugly. Maybe 1's and 0's but the "Y" just reminds me quicker of what the reason for the leaving the column visible is

Comment: @Vityata - if you want to make your last comment an answer I can credit you and close this out. It might help someone else too

Comment: @Berryl - ok, I will. Just a question - have you tried my code? What did it show?

Comment: @Vityata - just ran it. I get 89

Comment: @Berryl - 89 is the `Y` only https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

Comment: @Vityata - yes, Value2 to the rescue but seems bizarre to me still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general empty spaces in Excel sometimes cause a lot of problems. As the OP has found out himself, `.Value2` seems like a universal problem-solver of many strange cases.

Try to select the cell and check the following code, it will print possible "hidden" empty spaces:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cnt As Long

    Set rng = Selection
    For cnt = 1 To Len(rng)
        Debug.Print Asc(Mid(rng, cnt, 1))
    Next cnt
End Sub
```